# How to share session between multiple domains ? (same laravel application, different domain for each language)

Tags: laravel, session, cookies

My laravel application has a different domain for each locale (language), and I'm looking for a safe way to share the session between all the domains, any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: If you're using subdomains, I would recommend this link 
https://newbedev.com/laravel-share-session-data-over-multiple-domains
I haven't tried it yet, so I may do and answer you

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but I'm using a different domain for each language (like cars.com l, voitures.fr ...)